# Como obtener el % de Uso del CPU en Java?

Tags: java

He intentado obtener el porcentaje de uso del CPU con librerías de terceros y propias de java pero no lo consigo.

¿Me puede alguien indicar el método para obtener ese valor del rendimiento de mi computadora?

Comment: Hola @Dan. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías indicar tu sistema operativo y qué métodos intentaste hasta ahora? Ayudaría a acotar las respuestas. Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano esa información es irrelevante puesto que Java es multi plataforma. He encontrado una respuesta para esto en el sitio en inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/q/47177/1065197

Comment: @Luiggi Gracias por aclararlo. Haya o no una solución multiplataforma, mi comentario apunta a ver qué intentó y por qué está fallando. Creo que en varias de las respuestas de esa publicación comentan consideraciones según la plataforma, pero seguramente lo tengas más claro que yo. Era sólo la intención de guiar al autor de la pregunta para completarla hasta donde sea posible.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el API [SIGAR](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) que tiene todas las funcionalidades que necesitas para Java sobre diferentes plataformas. Te permite monitorear consumo de CPU, consumo de memoria, monitoreo de redes, monitoreo de sistema de archivos, etc.

Comment: No sé si has obtenido tu respuesta directamente de [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47290/1065197), lo noto porque inclusive usas **el mismo enlace** de dicha respuesta. De ser así, sería bueno editar la respuesta e indicar que esa es tu fuente. Ahora, personalmente no recomendaría usar una librería que no se actualiza hace más de 6 años, sabiendo que Java 7 está depreciado y que estamos a puertas de Java 9.